# Custom layout for EditTextPreference with null validation in custom dialog

Tags: android, view, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

I have PreferenceActivity in my app and I want to specify custom layout for EditTextPreference. 
I do it in an xml file with `android:layout` attribute. All is OK, the layout is getting changed but I can't change any value of its fields. The code is running without errors, in debug I can see that values are changed, but visually there are no changes.
I've tried to call `view.invalidate()` and `onContentChanged()` but nothing changed.
All of IDs are OK and no exceptions are being thrown. So I have no idea. I'll appreciate you help.

Here is code of my preferences_file_types.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="@string/preference_category_file_types"
        android:title="@string/settings_supported_file_types" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@string/preference_file_type_image"
            android:layout="@layout/file_types_list_item"
            android:title="@string/settings_supported_file_types_hint" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is code of my PreferenceActivity class:

```
public class FileTypesSettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences_file_types);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        EditTextPreference imageTypePreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.preference_file_type_image));
        View specifiedView = inflater.inflate(imageTypePreference.getLayoutResource(), null);
        changeViewAttributes(specifiedView);    
    }

    private void changeViewAttributes(View view) {
        ImageView fileTypeIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_types_list_item_iv_icon);
        fileTypeIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_file_image);

        TextView fileTypePredefined = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_types_list_item_tv_predefined_extensions);
        fileTypePredefined.setText("JPG BMP GIF PNG");

        TextView fileTypeAdded = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.file_types_list_item_tv_added_extensions);
        fileTypeAdded.setText("BLA BLA BLA");
    }
}
```